# iOS On Demand Resources dialog not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, on-demand-resources

I'm trying to create asset packs for hosting on my server. I'm following this guide: [Generating Hosted Asset Packs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/GeneratingHostedContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH19-SW1),
I do everything exactly as it is described and when it comes to this dialog in question, it just doesn't show. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

OK finally I came to a solution. It seems like a bug in xcode. If you have CloudKit enabled, right after you choose the team it asks you for a cloud container and miss out the on-demand resources dialog. What I did is turn off Cloud Kit, archive, generate asset packs, then turn back on Cloud Kit.
Hope it helps to someone having the same issue.